# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Tags: java, javafx

When I try to build my javafx application in intellij as a JavaFX Application and I run the jar in console with

> java -jar RaspberryShell.jar

I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class de.Jan.Raspberry.Shell.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

I also set the main class in the artifact that shouldn't be a problem and the code runs fine if I run it direct in intellij.

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: What Java version are you using? With Java 11 and onward, JavaFX is no longer shipped with the JRE/JDK and must be installed/downloaded separately (and added to the classpath when the program is started).

Comment: I'm using Java 8

Comment: @JanTennert Are you sure your java runtime is also java 8? (That is really old).

Comment: yes should be java 8 but I could test it with java 14

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to the path:

--module-path /usr/local/javafx-sdk-14.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

Just change /usr/local/javafx-sdk-14.0.1/lib to the directory which contain javafx. The lib directory should contain some .jar files, including javafx.fxml.jar

Comment: So I added this: `--module-path C:\Users\jan\Desktop\Programmieren\Java\Other\RaspberryShell\out\artifacts\RaspberryShell\javafx-sdk-14.0.2.1\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml` But now I got this error: Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Answer (score 0):

Your runtime Java does not include JavaFX.  Change to one who does.

Comment: And how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

**When  you run it, click on the drop down arrow -> Run configurations -> Arguments
Then paste the following into VM arguments: (Replace with your own path for lib)
--module-path "C:\Program Files\FX\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
Press apply and run!**

Answer (score 0):

This Error is because you may have two JDK installed on your machine an older version like Java 8 which contains a javafx/application/Application as part of the JDK and a higher which does not.
Solution:
Uninstall new JDK version and maintain JDK 8

Comment: This could be a comment